# Set the default color of a link within a container, without overriding other rules?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two containers: `left` and `right`

I'd like to set the default color of links in `left` to blue and `right` to red

This is not what I want:

```
.left a { color: #00F; }
.right a { color: #F00; }
```

The reason I don't want that, is because that snippet will overwrite every other `color` for `a` tags due to the css specificity rules.  See this jsfiddle  -- http://jsfiddle.net/jvanasco/q4oxmpxc/ -- in which the color for bootstrap's `label` class gets overridden

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/po65c21o/

Comment: Wow, @JoshCrozier, that's a nifty hack.  That might work in my situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to select `a` elements *without* a class. You could achieve this by combining the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [the attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[class]`.

In doing so, you are essentially negating all anchor elements *with* a class.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/po65c21o/)

```
.left a:not([class]) {
    color: #00F;
}
.right a:not([class]) {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: It's not really a hack - it just assumes that the only a elements with classes come from Bootstrap (or whatever) itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can this help you to fix the problem with `:not()` selector?

```
.left a:not(.label) {
    color: #00F;
}

.right a:not(.label) {
    color: #F00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4oxmpxc/3/

Comment: I think this is best bet without using JavaScript

Comment: That would only work for the .label classes; I'd have to create a `not` rule for every possible class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an extra CSS class to achieve this, eg:

```
.left .link {
    color: #00F;
}

<div class="left">
        <a href="#" class="link">Left</a>
</div>
```

Or do it like sdcr like mentioned above, but then for every problematic case you will have to add an extra "hack". Eg, if besides labels there is another issue in the future – you will have to edit stylesheet again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery:

```
$('.label').css('color','#fff');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/q4oxmpxc/4/